A function $S(x)$, such that $S(x^2)-x^2=S(x)$
$S(x)=S(x^2)-x^2$
I was trying to find a closed form for the following sum: $$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{2^n}$$ I deduced it down to the functional equation above. At first I was trying to convert it into the differential equation using the original definition, at some point I ended up with the following: $$x^2S''(x)+xS'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{2n}x^{2^n}$$ But I made a mistake, and came to the wrong equality: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{2n}x^{2^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{n}x^{2^n}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{2n-1}x^{2^n}$$ Then I tried to guess the shape of the function and set $S(x)=\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{mx^2+nx+l}$, after plugging it into the functional equation we end up with:$$\frac{ax^4+bx^2+c}{mx^4+n^2+l}-x^2=\frac{ax^2+bx+c}{mx^2+nx+l}$$ But after I cleared the denominator and equated the coeffitients all of them turned out to be zero. Also, if it is helpful, the function $xS'(x)$ somewhat looks either like a scaled $\\sinh(x)$ or like $\\sinh(f(x))$.
I start to think that there is no "nice" closed form for this function, but still I would really appreciate any help if someone would be able to go further than me.

If you evaluate at $x=1$ you get $S(1)-1=S(1)$ which seems to be rather impossible ... So maybe you don't want $1$  in the domain. But then $S(-1)+1=S(1)$ so $-1$ can't be in the domain as well.

From the power series expansion it is clear that the sum converges only on $(-1,1)$

Lacunary series such as $S(x)$ usually have no closed form.

Lacunary Function Wiki and a good conversation on this function at MathOverflow

The function $2^{\exp(x^2)}+2^{-\exp(x^2)}-2.5$ is similar.

The functional equation is wrong / has no solution of the form $S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{2^k}$. Prove: We can rewrite $S(x^2)$ to $S(x^2)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(x^{2})^{2^k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{2\cdot2^k}=\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^{2^k}$, so $S(x)-S(x^2)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty x^{2^k}-\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^{2^k}=x^{2}+\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^{2^k}-\sum_{k=2}^\infty x^{2^k}=x^2$. We can rewrite the functional equation to $S(x^2)-x^2=S(x)\Longleftrightarrow-x^{2}=S(x)-S(x^2)$. It follows $-x^2=x^{2}$ wich is wrong for all $x\in\mathbb{C}\setminus{0}$. The equation should be $S(x^2)+x^2=S(x)$.
